# How to add or remove a tag in a comma separated list attribute with ansible

Tags: ansible

I have some config files where I have lines like this:

```
   tags: mytag0, mytag1
```

I want to be able to use ansible to add/remove tags from these and my impression is that I cannot use `lineinfile` (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module to do this kind of operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `lineinfile` module and replace the entire line with the new line.

```
- replace:
    dest=some.conf
    state = present
    regexp=<your expression to match the existing tag line>
    line=<new tag line>
```

Use other parameters of `lineinfile` to suit to your needs. If you think this won't work, give us few examples. You can also use `replace` parameter for some cases.